# Difference between AccountId and WhatId in a Salesforce Task

Tags: rest-api, email, api

Specifically regarding Email objects in Salesforce's REST API, i get redundant `AccountId`s on fields- `AccountId` and `WhatId`. Seems like both of these are Accounts related to the `Task`.

My query to fetch emails is-

`SELECT AccountId,CreatedById,Description,Id,Subject,SystemModstamp,WhatId,WhoId FROM Task WHERE Subject LIKE 'Email: %'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `AccountId` is special part of the native display of "360 degree view" of the customer. This field can be used to query all tasks and events that tell a story around the Account. The value is populated automatically by all native objects that relate to Account directly or indirectly via `WhoId` or `WhatId`.

[image: task][image: event] [image: task][image: event] [image: task][image: event] [image: task][image: event] [image: task][image: event] (tasks and events `WhatId` related to native objects)

```
||   ||   ||   ||  ||
vv   vv   vv   vv  vv
```

[image: asset] [image: case] [image: contract] [image: opportunity] [image: order]

```
  \   \   |   /   /
   v   v  v  v   v
```

Account Id  [image: account] [image: task][image: event] (account also has own tasks and events)

```
         ^ ^
        /   \
```

[image: blank16] [image: blank32][image: contact] [image: lead]

```
       ^^   ^^
       ||   ||
```

[image: blank16][image: blank32] [image: task][image: event] [image: task][image: event] (tasks and events `WhoId` related to native objects)

WhatId:

- Account (the top of the graph from which all activities will be seen)
- Asset
- Case
- Contract
- Opportunity
- Order

WhoId:

- Contact (emails and calls to contacts will be seen on the Account)
- Lead (when converted, all prospecting activities remain on the Contact)

Use the `AccountId` instead of the `WhatId` to get the full picture like this:

```
List<Task> emails = [
    SELECT Id, Subject, Description
    FROM Task
    WHERE AccountId = :accountId
    AND Subject LIKE 'Email:%'
];
```

It is also possible for Tasks and Events hanging off **Custom Objects** to appear on the Account, if that object is designed with a Master-Detail relationship to Account. This doesn't work when it is a Lookup relationship, or when the relationship connects to other native objects hanging off Account.

Answer (score 3):

Task API object [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)

"This is the account of WhatId if it exists, otherwise it’s the account of WhoId if it exists, otherwise it’s set to null"